# Finding a simple set up to use Cloudfront with a node.js express app

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, pug, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to set up **Cloudfront** in my nodeJS Express app (using Jade as a rendering engine) with the following requirements:

- Only use Cloudfront on production server (not on localhost or staging server)
- Not using a conditional statement on all scripts and css in the jade templates
- Trying to find a one or two liner in case I need to switch to a different provider

I came up with one possible solution: overriding how Jade renders links and scripts and adding the Cloudfront url only on production:

```
Jade.override(“link”,function(){
if(prod) link.src = cloudfront_url + link.src
})
```

However, Jade doesn't allow overriding any its functions. Does anybody know an easy way to use Cloudfront on a node app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have a 2 liner for you but I think this will give you a lot of flexibility. The first step is to assign the base url to a local variable that is shared with all your templates on the `res.locals` property like so:

```
// add this to app.js
// its VERY important that this app.use comes BEFORE app.set('view engine'....
var isProd = true;
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.CDN_URI = isProd ? 'http://zzzz.cloudfront' : '';
  next();
});

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
.....
```

Then, step two is the slightly painful part - you need to update all of your templates to call CDN_URI before all your assets that you want to serve from cloudfront:

`img(src="#{CDN_URI}/img/logo.jpg")`

`script(src="#{CDN_URI}/js/main.min.js")`

`link(rel="stylesheet", href="#{CDN_URI}/stylesheets/style.css")`

So it will be a little work upfront, but I do believe this will give you maximum flexibility if you need to change the CDN_URI in the future, or if you setup multiple environments(dev, test, stage, etc.)

Also, I don't think you would want to blindly prepend the cdn url to ALL of your src attributes because you may end up(if you aren't already) pulling in images/scripts from third party websites - using this "CDN_URI" tag approach will allow you to pick and choose which assets load from cloudfront.

Comment: Thanks for that! I ending up usin a mixin in my jade templates but I had to update all the links that use Cloudfront. You solution is actually better.